# Initialising class members - default values or member-init-list?

Tags: c++, default-value, initializer-list, default-constructor, member-initialization

I'm a bit confused about when and how to initialize members of a class in a constructor. If I understand things correctly, you can accomplish this by either including default values in the class definition, a constructor member initialiser list, or via assignment in the body of the constructor. I realise that it's best to initialize before entering the body of the constructor, but when should you use a member initialiser list and when should you use default values?

Apologies if I've fundamentally misunderstood something here.

Comment: @Andreas: that question says nothing about default values in the class definition, which is mainly what this question is about.

Comment: *"when should you use a member initialiser list and when should you use default values"* Use whatever is more convenient for you, they effectively do the same thing.

Comment: @TonyK Classes, unless singletons, are assumed to be reused. Having default values is useful for specific members, if those mostly carry the same values. If not, then default values simply won't work (simplified). In the body of this question, it seems to me as if this person actually needs help with the difference between initializer lists and assignment in the body of the constructor, because they've misunderstood what constructors are, and how they work. That's why I flagged this question as a duplicate. Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: This is not a question about a problem you're having, so it's off-topic on SO. The answer would be mostly opinion-based anyway. My answer would be that as a general rule of thumb, use inline initialization if you can. If you can't, use a constructor initializer list. If you can't, assign values in the constructor body.

Comment: This question seems perfectly on-topic to me.

Comment: @TonyK When a question is on-topic on SO, it means that it should be answerable with an answer that solves the problem and is "correct." I don't think this can be achieved here. You can get different answers depending on people's opinions and coding style and it's not possible to objectively say which ones are "right" and which ones are "wrong."

Comment: @NikosC.thanks for pointing me on this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization

Answer (score 2):

Your are really confusing things a bit. There are at least 4 different concepts

- [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments)
- [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)
- initialization in constructor [body](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions) (even constructors can have a non-trivial body)
- [inline member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)<sup>[1]</sup>

you made 3 of.

In the following examples <sup>([at ideone.com](https://ideone.com/CVZ2Me))</sup> I use `struct` instead of `class` and inline constructors for brevity/simplicitly.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{ 
    A(int v=1): m(v) {}
    int m; 
};

struct B
{ 
    B(): m(2) {}
    int m; 
};

struct C
{ 
    C()
    {
        m = 3;
    }
    int m; 
};

// since C++11
struct D
{ 
    int m = 11; 
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    #define TRACE(arg) cout << #arg ": " << arg.m << endl; 
    A a1;
    TRACE(a1)
    A a2(4); 
    TRACE(a2)
    B b;
    TRACE(b)
    b.m = 5;
    TRACE(b)
    C c;
    TRACE(c)
    c.m = 6;
    TRACE(c)
    D d;
    TRACE(d)
    d.m = 0;
    TRACE(d)
    #undef TRACE
}
```

The usage of `A` differs from that of `B`, `C` and `D`.

Only `A` provides a way to initialize `m` with a value other than the default. All variants provide direct access to `m` (mostly not a good choice, see it as a placeholder for a more sophisticated way to modify a member). You have to *modify* an object if there is no access to the actual initializer value(s). This makes `m` for *constant* objects of `B`, `C` and `D` effectively a compile-time constant. Member "initialization" in the constuctor body (`C`) should be avoided if an initializer list (`A` or `B`) can be used (sometimes this is not as trivial as shown here).

Option `D` should be estimated if you are using C++11 or later.

So `A` seems the most flexible option. But it's not a good pattern for initializing two or more members: it's too easy to mix up the parameter order.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> this option was added after I (thanks to [NikosC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55777933/initialising-class-members-default-values-or-member-init-list/56037974#comment98228849_55777933)) realized that this options existed